# Bootstrap 4 Dynamic WordPress Carousel Won't Slide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dynamic carousel using Bootstrap 4 and WordPress. I have the title and first image appearing on the front-end correctly but I can't get the carousel to slide to the next image and title.

I checked the DOM and `the data-slide-to` is updating the `$number` on the associated `<a>` tags correctly on each slide. So I'm not sure why when I click the `<a>` tags it won't slide to the next image in the carousel.

I have tested the HTML by hard-coding HTML as a test and it works fine, I am loading in jQuery and the Bootstrap4 JS correctly. Additionally, since the `data-slide-to` has the correct numbers in the DOM I'm not sure what part of the code is causing the slider to not move forward.

**HTML/PHP - Bootstrap 4**

```
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <?php 
     $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
      'category_name' => 'Featured', 
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'offset' => 0
      )); 
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
     $the_query->the_post();
?>
<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>');">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="slider-sub"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
  endwhile; 
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div><!-- END CAROUSEL INNER -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row slider-row">
    <?php 
      $number = 0; 
      query_posts('category_name=featured'); 
      if(have_posts()):  
    ?>

    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box highlight carousel1">
        <a data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>" class="active carousel-link"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div><!-- END COL -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div><!-- END ROW -->
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any error messages?

Comment: Indeed I have the console has no errors. I was able to get very similar code to work on Bootstrap 3 and I'm at a loss on what I have missed here.

Comment: Why don't you post the problematic HTML? Or, better yet, look at it to see where it's wrong and let us know.

Comment: I believe it's a problematic PHP issue. The HTML above is the only HTML. I *believe* the issue is somewhere after `div class="row slider-row">` but I am entirely uncertain.  Therefore I show the carousel in it's entirety that is built with PHP and HTML. If I could pinpoint where it was I would have been able to resolve it myself. The image appears, the post appears and the two other links appear - it just doesn't change slides to my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working. I rewrote how the posts were being called and I learned that even though I'm hiding carousel indicators, the slider wouldn't change slides without them being part of the HTML. Not sure if that's just on my end or a rule with Bootstrap but that was my experience. You can see in my code I try to replace changing slides with links, which do work but the indicators must still exist in the HTML. If they are removed, it will not work.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'category_name' => 'Featured'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query ( $args ); 
?>
<div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <!-- Start Carousel Indicator Loop -->
  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <li data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $the_query->current_post; ?>" class="<?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>"></li>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ol>
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>    


<div class="carousel-inner"> 
  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  ?>

  <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
  <div style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>');" class="carousel-item <?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> </a>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <p class="d-none d-sm-block"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div><!-- /.carousel-item -->
    <!-- end second loop -->
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row slider-row carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box highlight carousel1">
        <a data-target="#my-carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $the_query->current_post; ?>" class="carousel-link <?php if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div><!-- END COL -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

  </div><!-- END ROW -->
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```